# What is the difference between Integrated Security=True vs Encrypt=Yes usage?

Tags: c#, sql, string, security, encryption

What is the difference between the purpose of Integrated Security = true/SSPI and Encrypt = yes in connection string? Does it suffice for security purposes to just enable Integrated Security without using "Encrypt"?

Thank you

Comment: These two are not related. `Integrated Security` is There to decide how the user should be authenticated when connecting to database. Encrypt is to decide whether the sql server should use an SSL certificate to encrypt the data while transferring over the network between server and the client. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Hi chrizzy, would you mind adding a bit more context and details about language/systems/libraries and whatever could make your question more useful to the StackOverflow community?

Comment: Integrated Security uses Windows credential to access the sql database.  It is the same as using a remote desktop connection to access an account on a remote PC.  I do not think Encrypt is then needed.  I think if you use SQL credentials instead of Windows credentials then Encrypt option should be used.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: I think your comment should be an (the) answer.

Comment: @jdweng thank you that was the kind of answer I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

`Integrated Security` and `Encrypt` options in database Connection string are not related. They both have different purpose and they do not interfere with each other.

`Integrated Security` is There to decide how the user should be authenticated when connecting to database. If `Integrated Security` is set to `True` the connection request is made for the currently logged in Windows User. Instead, if the connection should be made for a database user such as `sa`, `Integrated Security` option is not required in the connection string. Only username and password of the database user is provided in the connection string.

On the other hand `Encrypt` is to decide whether the sql server should use an SSL certificate to encrypt the data while transferring over the network between server and the client.

You can get more details about various options in database connection string at following Microsoft page.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thank you. So would you say it is best practice from a security standpoint to set both Integrated Security and Encrypt to true? Or would it be safe to just use Windows Authentication without Encrypt?